# How do I vertically center text and have the dark blue bar go across the entire screen

Tags: html, css

I'd like to vertically and horizontally center my text "New from Subaru". Also, I have a dark blue background on the text. I would like that dark blue background to extend horizontally on the entire div. How would I do that?

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/eL7rwLx3/21/

```css
wrapper-promo { background-color: #3862ad; border: 2px solid #2251a4; margin: 10px 0; width: 500px; }

.title-top {
    background-color: #2251a4;
    display: table;
    height: 40px;  
    overflow: hidden;
}


.title-top-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.promo-content {
    margin: 20px;
}

h2 {
    font-family:SegoeBold;
    font-size:1.4em;
    color:#fff;
    margin: 10px 0 -10px 0;
}

h2.block-title {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    font-family:SegoeBold;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#fff;
}
 .promo-content p {
     font-family: helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-promo">
<div class="title-top">
    <div class="title-top-cell">
        <h2 class="block-title">New from Subaru</h2></div></div>
    <div class="promo-content">
        <h2>
            Subaru Guide for Small Business</h2>
        <h3>
            Starts at $45/month</h3>
        <p>
            Adventure has a stylish side. The 2015 Subaru Outback was designed to allow you to experience the world like you never have before.</p>                
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this it will stretch out your block title div all the way in your title-pop div.

```
h2.block-title {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I think I can just do it without having the Table. I could just put this under the .title-top tag:

    height: 40px;  
    line-height: 40px;

Comment: You did not show the wrapper-promo css. As long as you have the block-title div inside of this, it will stretch that blue bar the entire width if you set it to 100%.